System keeps going to Screensaver after latest LTS update
After I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 I noticed that my system goes to screensaver after a specific time period. I am using Caffeine to prevent the system from going idle and it worked without any issue in the previous LTS, but now it keeps happening all the time. I am using XFCE 4.18 I notices that when you adjust the panel from 24px default to a larger size and activate caffeine the system will go idle after you stop using it. When you readjust it to the default 24px it will go idle as well, but it wont happen all the time just occasionally. Does anyone have similar issue with the system going to screensaver and idle even if you don't want it to after you did the upgrade? I even tried using the Stimulator Flatpak app to prevent it from going idle and it still does.
When you deactivate and reactivate caffeine the problem goes away, but only for a brief period. After you finish doing whatever you do and leave it it will again go to screensaver.
